# Symfony 2.8 - SQL: No such file or directory in "test" environment only

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, phpunit, sulu

I'm really struggling to get this issue fixed.
I have several Symfony projects I have been working on for months. Since last week, the "test" environment does not work anymore. It just cannot connect to the Mysql DB. This issue is present throughout all Symfony projects. The database config has not been changed and was working perfectly until last week. There is, and always was, a separate DB for the test environment. I did not update any dependencies or something. The weirdest thing is, that all is fine in prod or dev environment.

It really sucks, not being able to run tests locally, so I hope for your expertise!

Thanks in advance and cheers!

`config_test.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        host: localhost
        dbname: rims_test
        user: root
        password:
```

[image: Screenshot: dev vs. test env]

[image: Screenshot: Error - Verbose info]

Comment: do your mariadb installation listen to a sockets or IP:port? if it listens on the local IP you could use `host: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: You were right! The problem was that the `parameters.yml` for the dev and prod environment used `127.0.0.1` as the DB host and the `config_test.yml` that overwrites these params was using `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! alexander-schranz and johannes-wachter from the Sulu.io team provided me with this solution. Thanks a lot!

The solution was to remove a part of the test config:

`config_test.yml`: BEFORE

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        host: localhost
        dbname: rims_test
        user: root
        password:
```

`config_test.yml`: AFTER (Working again!)

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname: rims_test
```